# websql console in safari specifically for debugging in iOS

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari, web-sql, safari-web-inspector

[image]

attached screenshot from chrome developer tools, how can I see the same for Safari specifically mobile safari, as I'm debugging on Safari from my attached iPad, how can I see the tables in it.

Update:

I see a database button in this video, but I can't seem to have it in my current version of Safari.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1940-My-Safari-Browser-SQLite-Database-Hello-World-Example.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing the refresh button (right next to the .html page in the Resources list) in the Safari Web Inspector will reload the resources and you will be able to see the WebSQL Databases.

Comment: There's a databases folder under the html page, I'll take it as the right answer.

Comment: I unable to find the WebSQL database during debugging on an app on iPhone, Please mention all the steps.